# Satellite Images on OPeNDAP

Tags: data-request, geospatial

I am looking for global satellite images(as recent as possible - say three hours ago) of meteorological data that can be accessed through OPeNDAP protocol i.e. subsetting via latitude, longitude and time. Meteosat does have them but only upto 2015 - [Meteosat OPeNDAP](http://opendap.knmi.nl/knmi/thredds/catalog/ADAGUC/testsets/projectedgrids/meteosat/catalog.html)
I am looking for current global satellite images that can be accessed via OPeNDAP. 
For continental USA this site does provide the images - [CONUS](http://thredds.ucar.edu/thredds/idd/satellite.html)

Answer (score 0):

NASA's [worldview](https://worldview.earthdata.nasa.gov/) app is pretty cool and might be a good starting place, but for OPenDAP access you probably want to look into one of NASA's [DAACs](https://earthdata.nasa.gov/about/daacs). For example, the Physical Oceanography DAAC, PODAAC has an OPeNDAP server located [here](https://opendap.jpl.nasa.gov/opendap/).

Comment: I checked the site but the images available via OPeNDAP are not current. But still a good site and happily upvoted

Comment: I'm not sure about OPeNDAP, but [NASA's LANCE](https://earthdata.nasa.gov/earth-observation-data/near-real-time/download-nrt-data) website may have something helpful if your priority is getting the data as fast as possible.

Comment: great site for current satellite images. I will send them a note asking them to put their images on OPeNDAP. The reason I want this is because I want to invoke OPeNDAP via Python and link it to the rest of my application